# Display contents of domain folder on sub domain root

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, hosting, vhosts

I have a website at root of main domain, let's call it domain(dot)com, this site runs a template based system through htaccess, similar to wordpress.
On there i have a section called domain(dot)com/forum/, the folder doesn't exist as it's managed through the template system and htaccess.

I'm trying to find a solution where i create a subdomain on the same domain above and all works as if they are on domain(dot)com/forum/ but are in fact on forum(dot)domain(dot)com.

Is this in fact possible as the htaccess file on the main site controls all the structure?

I have searched everywhere from symlinks to vhosts document root but cannot find a solution to this.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the forum.domain.com public directory folder add a htaccess file and add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain.com/forum/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, the htaccess code caused a 500 server error. Is it because the only files i have at root of the main site are .htaccess and index.php. I don't have a physical directory called /forum/?

Comment: Post your error log messages here. Should be in logs/error_log

Comment: Hi here's the error log...  `[Thu May 23 06:04:38 2013] [error] [client 109.144.237.206] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`